# Replacing different characters with one

Tags: javascript, replace, special-characters

I have this code:
`.replace(/\ /g, "-");`
that replaces every space with a dash. Now, how do I filter out non-letter characters to be replaced with a dash. I have tried `.replace(/\ 12345/g, "-");` (a space and numbers 1-5) but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

`.replace(/[ A-Za-z]/g, "-");`

will replace A-Z, a-z and spaces.

Comment: Okay. Thanks. :) It works. But I have one question, if I were to filter out all the non-letter characters, shall I type all of them? or is there a shorthand method for it?

Comment: You can use charset negation. .replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, "-")

Comment: Psst, the `^` goes inside the `[]`

Comment: There's no need for a backslash (\\) before the space, maybe you meant to use `\s`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]+/g, '-');
```